# Manipulate textbox on gridview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to create a table like figure. When I click Edit I need textbox of that row in column change to enable.
[image: ...]

My event has this code. The problem is `GVBookDetails.FindControl` is returning null and I can't understand why because I have that control.

```
protected void btnEditQuantity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int productID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as Button).CommandArgument); // get productID from EditButton
    Book book = (Book)Session["BookID"]; // object instance to use in edit query

    TextBox textBox = GVBookDetails.FindControl("tbQuantityEdit") as TextBox;

    textBox.Enabled = true;
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: It is bad thing to do it with `FindConrol`. Could you explain how are you adding buttons?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantityEdit" Enabled="false" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>' TextMode="Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: inside a gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to find the TextBox in the GridView itself. Not the row that the button and the textbox are in.
You can use the NamingContainer of the sender to find the TextBox.

```
protected void btnEditQuantity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a button
    Button cb = sender as Button;

    //get the current gridviewrow from the button namingcontainer
    GridViewRow row = cb.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    //use findcontrol to locate the textbox in that row
    TextBox tb = row.FindControl("tbQuantityEdit") as TextBox;

    //do something with the textbox
    tb.Text = "TextBox found!";
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. And remember that items in a GridView or Repeater are Index based. So if you wanted the textbox in the 5th row you could also do this `GVBookDetails.Rows[4].FindControl("tbQuantityEdit")`